# Amazon s3 object filter by date

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to filter s3 objects inside a bucket by last modified date

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2).build();
ListObjectsV2Result result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(bucketName, date);
                List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = result.getObjectSummaries();
List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = result.getObjectSummaries(); //contains objects
```

Here In s3, I have a bucket. Inside the bucket, there will be the folder with dates. The data for the particular date accumulated to the corresponding date folder. Inside the date folder, JSON objects and modified date is there.I want to fetch the json objects with date range.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Perhaps you can edit your question to show a sample folder structure? When you say ".I want to fetch the json objects with date range", do you mean you wish to download all files within a particular folder (and if so, which folder)? Have you actually tried something and you are having a particular problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response.Actually I have a bucket named analytics,inside that objects are stored as name(object as json ),lastmodified,size,storageclass.I am trying to filter the objects by lastmodified

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to filter the objects by lastmodified"? The `lastmodified` date is returned as part of the `objects` listing. You can write your code to loop through the listing to find the objects of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

S3 does not support retrieving an object listing filtered by date.

As @John noted above, you will need to iterate through the listing and evaluate the filter condition in your code.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this?

Comment: @Trevor neither the original [`ListObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) nor the newer [`ListObjectsV2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) API actions for S3 support date range related request parameters.  S3 does not appear to expose any interface allowing this kind of querying of objects based on metadata.