# Get the latest "last modifed date" from files in S3 bucket with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I would like to ask about the most efficient way to get the latest "last modified date" from files in a S3 bucket.

From the solutions I see so far, the solution used is to keep track of a "lastModfiedDate" variable, and keep updating it.
i.e. something like

```
        ...
        do {
        result = amazonS3.listObjectsV2(request);
        result.getObjectSummaries().forEach(s -> {
            Date lastModified = s.getLastModified();
            if (latestObjectDateTime.isBefore(lastModified.getTime())) {
                latestObjectDateTime.setTime(new DateTime(lastModified));
            }
        });
        ...
```

The solution should work, but the problem is that it needs to loop all the files inside the bucket. There are tens of thousands of files coming into the bucket everyday. If every time it needs to loop through all the files inside the bucket it is quite inefficient. Is there  a more efficient way to achieve the same?

Comment: As already mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54040401/5499287 S3 SDK does not support filtering by modification date.

Comment: You could use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.